# installed php-curl still PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-curl

I have installed php-curl using

**sudo apt-get install php-curl**
But I'm still getting
"PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init()"

Then I tried **sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl**
It shows

"php5.6-curl is already the newest version"

Then I tried **sudo apt-get install php5-curl**  it shows

"The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php5-curl : Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4) but 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.23 is to be installed"

My php version is **PHP 5.6.36-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)**

still I'm getting this fatal error , Please help me . I'm not able to make a http call from my program.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you have multiple versions of PHP installed.   Use phpinfo() to confirm that your web server is using 5.6.36.

Comment: i dunno about ubuntu, maybe **[this is relevant to enabling/disabling php modules](https://tecadmin.net/enable-disable-php-modules-ubuntu/)**,

Comment: You are correct , while checking php version of web server , it shows "5.5.9-1ubuntu4.23".

But I don't know how to install php-curl for version 5.5.9.